# HTML Button: click and redirect to another link on Server with Get method

Tags: html, button

I have this simple code for example:

```
<form method="GET" action="test1.do">
  <input type="SUBMIT" value="test 1">
</form>
<form method="GET" action="test2.do">
  <input type="SUBMIT" value="test 2">
</form>
```

`tes1.do` and `test2.do` is anything on server, in my case, these are servlets.

I want more simple by just create a button. But,  I don't know how can when user click, it will redirect with "GET" method because button doesn't have GET Attribute.

Thanks :)

Comment: So, you would like to join both forms into one, with two different submit buttons?

Comment: You're treating your buttons as links.  Perhaps your should use links instead.

Comment: @webdeskil No. you cannot. because each form has each special action (tes1.do and test2.do), we cannot combine those button into one form.

Comment: @CraigO but, that button doesn't have method attribute as I say.  !!!

Comment: Links of the form <a href="[url]">Foo Bar</a> always use the GET method.  Forms have the option of using a different HTTP request method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try add name on there. On top of that if the user click test 2 it should take you to test2.